# Use force and delay to produce stream of even integers in generate-and-filter style

Tags: stream, scheme, filtering, delayed-execution

I am trying to learn the use of `delay` and `force` in Scheme. I created a function which outputs the even numbers in the list. Now I am trying to use `delay` and `force` with function. But I am getting `error : unbound symbol : "delay" []`.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
(define (even-filter ls)
  (if (null? ls)  '()
    (filter even? ls)))

(even-filter '(1 2 3 4 5 88))

(let ((delayed (delay (even-filter '(1 2 3 4 5 88)))))
  (force delayed))
```

Comment: what Scheme implementation are you using? the error is saying that the function `delay` isn't defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're using the right language, because both `force` and `delay` are primitive forms, part of the standard language. If using Racket, in the bottom-left corner select "Determine language from source", and type the following:

```
#lang racket

(define (even-filter ls)
  (filter even? ls))

(let ((delayed (delay (even-filter '(1 2 3 4 5 88)))))
  (force delayed))
```

It works as expected:

```
'(2 4 88)
```

Comment: the indentation is botched , but `delayed` is *inside* the `let` which defined it. the error is *`unbound symbol : "delay"`* (some library loading problems? the implementation is not specified...)

Comment: @WillNess good catch! I rewrote my answer assuming that OP is using Racket, errors like this are common when the wrong language is selected.

Comment: I was using "repl.it" online interpreter, code did not work, but when I tried it on "Racket" it worked. Thanks